# Matching target to target names in fetch_20newsgroups

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is probably a dumb question, but I cannot find a way to match the target label in the `fetch_20newsgroups` to the target name. Is it something as obvious as `alt.atheism` == `1` and that's why I can't find it anywhere, or is there a method to match that I'm just not finding?

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
>>> newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(list(newsgroups_train.target_names))
['alt.atheism',
 'comp.graphics',
 'comp.os.ms-windows.misc',
 'comp.sys.ibm.pc.hardware',
 'comp.sys.mac.hardware',
 'comp.windows.x',
 'misc.forsale',
 'rec.autos',
 'rec.motorcycles',
 'rec.sport.baseball',
 'rec.sport.hockey',
 'sci.crypt',
 'sci.electronics',
 'sci.med',
 'sci.space',
 'soc.religion.christian',
 'talk.politics.guns',
 'talk.politics.mideast',
 'talk.politics.misc',
 'talk.religion.misc']
>>> newsgroups_train.target[:10]
array([12,  6,  9,  8,  6,  7,  9,  2, 13, 19])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely not a dumb question as I also couldn't find any documentations on this.

I took a look at the source code of `fetch_20newsgroups` function from [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/datasets/_twenty_newsgroups.py#L149).

```py
def fetch_20newsgroups(data_home=None, subset='train', categories=None,  # line#-149
                       shuffle=True, random_state=42,
                       remove=(),
                       download_if_missing=True, return_X_y=False):
    """Load the filenames and data from the 20 newsgroups dataset \
(classification).
    Download it if necessary.
...
...
    categories : None or collection of string or unicode                 # line#-177
        If None (default), load all the categories.
        If not None, list of category names to load (other categories
        ignored).
...
...
    """
...
...
    if categories is not None:                                           # line#-287
        labels = [(data.target_names.index(cat), cat) for cat in categories]
        # Sort the categories to have the ordering of the labels
        labels.sort()
        labels, categories = zip(*labels)
        mask = np.in1d(data.target, labels)
        data.filenames = data.filenames[mask]
        data.target = data.target[mask]                                  # line#-294
        # searchsorted to have continuous labels
        data.target = np.searchsorted(labels, data.target)
        data.target_names = list(categories)
        # Use an object array to shuffle: avoids memory copy
        data_lst = np.array(data.data, dtype=object)
        data_lst = data_lst[mask]
        data.data = data_lst.tolist()
...
...
    return data
```

Notice that one of the parameter is `categories` AND from the docstring,

> If None (default), load all the categories.
>   If not None, list of category names to load

So there is a default `categories` with all the `target_names`.

Now, let's go to the line#-287 of the source code.
You can see that when the `categories` is given, it is sorted based on the index of each `category` from the `target_names`.

And later on line#-294, `target` is filtered based on those indexes.
Which tells us that those numbers you get from `target` are actually
the indexes of the categories from the `target_names`.

Therefore you can match each of them by its index from the `target_names`.

```py
for idx, cat in enumerate(newsgroups_train.target_names):
    print(idx, cat)
```

```py
0 alt.atheism
1 comp.graphics
2 comp.os.ms-windows.misc
3 comp.sys.ibm.pc.hardware
4 comp.sys.mac.hardware
5 comp.windows.x
6 misc.forsale
7 rec.autos
8 rec.motorcycles
9 rec.sport.baseball
10 rec.sport.hockey
11 sci.crypt
12 sci.electronics
13 sci.med
14 sci.space
15 soc.religion.christian
16 talk.politics.guns
17 talk.politics.mideast
18 talk.politics.misc
19 talk.religion.misc
```